# Objective C - If statement on CGRectmake?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgpoint, cgrect

here is what im trying to accomplish here. I want a image to start from the top of the screen and go to the bottem, then when it gets to the bottem it goes back up again. I am able to get the image to go down by doing this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0];
[image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 1500)];
[UIView commitAnimations];


if ([image setFrame:CGPoint =(0, 0, 30, 1500)]) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0];
    [image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 0)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}
```

This if statement doesnt work, im not sure how to make this work. Im very new to using points.

Or maybe a while loop? Any ideas? 
Thanks Very Much!

Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will not run for a start because this line is not valid

```
if ([image setFrame:CGPoint =(0, 0, 30, 1500)]) {
```

I believe you meant to compare the location of the view

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint(image.frame.origin, CGPointMake(0, 0))) {
```

Your image width is also set to `1500` in places which does not seem quite right

The final reason this will not work is because the UIView will look at the net changes in location and realise that the view does not move therefore it won't do anything.

What you would need to do is maybe use blocks like this

```
float duration = 0.5;
int delay = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:delay
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations: ^{
                     image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 460, 30, 30);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                                           delay:delay
                                         options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                                      animations: ^{
                                          image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
                                      } completion:nil];
                 }];
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is a bit confused:

```
if ([image setFrame:CGPoint =(0, 0, 30, 1500)]) {
```

The `-[NSView setFrame]` function **sets** a view's frame. It can't be used to check what the current frame is - for that, you'd use something like:

```
if (CGRectEqualToRect([image frame], CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 1500))) {
```

which uses the `-[NSView frame]` function to get the current frame, and `CGRectEqualToRect` to compare it.